# Submitting to a database with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I found the first part and tried to expand it, but the code won't work. I have a index part and a create part, but when I press "submit" in my code nothing is submitted. The two looks the same and don't know why this wont work. I set up a database using xampp and it works perfectly with the original code

In the original code when I press "submit", the data is stored in the database and the user is taken back to the index page, in my code the form resets and the data is not stored. I don't get an error message.

This is the original code:

index part;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                </p>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Name</th>
                          <th>Email Address</th>
                          <th>Mobile Number</th>
                          <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
                       include 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY id DESC';
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['name'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['email'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['mobile'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=250>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                                echo ' ';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                                echo ' ';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }
                       Database::disconnect();
                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

The create part:

```
<?php

    require 'database.php';

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track validation errors
       // $nameError = null;
        $emailError = null;
        $mobileError = null;

        // keep track post values
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

        // validate input
        $valid = true;
        /*if (empty($name)) {
            $nameError = 'Please enter Name';
            $valid = false;
        }*/

        if (empty($email)) {
            $emailError = 'Please enter Email Address';
            $valid = false;
        } else if ( !filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
            $emailError = 'Please enter a valid Email Address';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (empty($mobile)) {
            $mobileError = 'Please enter Mobile Number';
            $valid = false;
        }

        // insert data
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name,email,mobile) values(?, ?, ?)";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($name,$email,$mobile));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

                <div class="span10 offset1">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3>Create a Customer</h3>
                    </div>

                    <form class="form-horizontal" action="create.php" method="post">
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($nameError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="name" type="text"  placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo !empty($name)?$name:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($nameError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $nameError;?></span>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($emailError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Email Address</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="<?php echo !empty($email)?$email:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($emailError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $emailError;?></span>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($mobileError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">Mobile Number</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input name="mobile" type="text"  placeholder="Mobile Number" value="<?php echo !empty($mobile)?$mobile:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($mobileError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $mobileError;?></span>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                          <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I made:

index part;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>PHP CRUD Grid</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p>
                    <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success">Create</a>
                </p>

                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>titel</th>
                          <th>prog</th>
                          <th>tekst</th>
                          <th>alt1</th>
                             <th>res1</th>
                          <th>alt2</th>
                          <th>res2</th>
                          <th>alt3</th>
                               <th>res3</th>
                          <th>alt4</th>
                          <th>res4</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                      <?php
                       include 'database.php';
                       $pdo = Database::connect();
                       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM sider ORDER BY id DESC';
                       foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                                echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['titel'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['progresjon'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['tekst'] . '</td>';
                                      echo '<td>'. $row['alt1'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['res1'] . '</td>';
                                  echo '<td>'. $row['alt2'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['res2'] . '</td>';
                                        echo '<td>'. $row['alt3'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['res3'] . '</td>';
                                  echo '<td>'. $row['alt4'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td>'. $row['res4'] . '</td>';
                                echo '<td width=250>';
                                echo '<a class="btn" href="read.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Read</a>';
                                echo ' ';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                                echo ' ';
                                echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                                echo '</td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                       }
                       Database::disconnect();
                      ?>
                      </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- /container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Create part:

```
<?php

    require 'database.php';

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track validation errors
        $titelError = null;
        $progresjonError = null;
        $tekstError = null;

        // keep track post values
        $titel = $_POST['titel'];
        $progresjon = $_POST['progresjon'];
        $tekst = $_POST['tekst'];
        $alt1 = $_POST['alt1'];
        $res1 = $_POST['res1'];
        $alt2 = $_POST['alt2'];
        $res2 = $_POST['res2'];
        $alt3 = $_POST['alt3'];
        $res3 = $_POST['res3'];
        $alt4 = $_POST['alt4'];
        $res4 = $_POST['res4'];



        // validate input
        $valid = true;
        if (empty($titel)) {
            $titelError = 'Please enter titel';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (empty($progresjon)) {
            $progresjonError = 'Please enter progresjon';
            $valid = false;
        }

        if (empty($tekst)) {
            $tekstError = 'Please enter tekst';
            $valid = false;
        }

        // insert data
        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO sider (titel,progresjon,tekst,alt1,res1,alt2,res2,alt3,res3,alt4,res4) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($titel,$progresjon,$tekst,$alt1,$res1,$alt2,$res2,$alt3,$res3,$alt4,$res4));
            Database::disconnect();
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <div class="span10 offset1">
                <div class="row">
                    <h3>Create a Customer</h3>
                </div>

                <form class="form-horizontal" action="create.php" method="post">
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($titelError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">titel</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input titel="titel" type="text" placeholder="titel" value="<?php echo !empty($titel)?$titel:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($titelError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $titelError;?></span>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($progError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">prog Address</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input titel="progresjon" type="text" placeholder="progresjon" value="<?php echo !empty($progresjon)?$progresjon:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($progresjonError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $progresjonError;?></span>
                                <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="control-group <?php echo !empty($tekstError)?'error':'';?>">
                        <label class="control-label">tekst </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <input titel="tekst" type="text" placeholder="tekst Number" value="<?php echo !empty($tekst)?$tekst:'';?>">
                            <?php if (!empty($tekstError)): ?>
                                <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $tekstError;?></span>
                                <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <div class="control-group">
                            <label class="control-label">alt1</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input titel="alt1" type="text" placeholder="Alt1" value="<?php echo !empty($alt1)?$alt1:'';?>" </div>


                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="control-group">
                                <label class="control-label">res1</label>
                                <div class="controls">
                                    <input titel="res1" type="text" placeholder="res1" value="<?php echo !empty($res1)?$res1:'';?>" </div>


                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">alt2</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input titel="al1" type="text" placeholder="Alt2" value="<?php echo !empty($alt2)?$alt2:'';?>" </div>


                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                        <label class="control-label">res2</label>
                                        <div class="controls">
                                            <input titel="res2" type="text" placeholder="res2" value="<?php echo !empty($res2)?$res2:'';?>" </div>


                                        </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label">alt3</label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <input titel="al3" type="text" placeholder="Alt3" value="<?php echo !empty($alt3)?$alt3:'';?>" </div>


                                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="control-group">
                                                <label class="control-label">res3</label>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <input titel="res3" type="text" placeholder="res3" value="<?php echo !empty($res3)?$res3:'';?>" </div>


                                                </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="control-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label">alt4</label>
                                                    <div class="controls">
                                                        <input titel="alt4" type="text" placeholder="Alt4" value="<?php echo !empty($alt4)?$alt4:'';?>" </div>


                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>

                                                    <div class="control-group">
                                                        <label class="control-label">res4</label>
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <input titel="res4" type="text" placeholder="res4" value="<?php echo !empty($res4)?$res4:'';?>" </div>

                                                             </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                                                                                <div class="form-actions">
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
                                                            <a class="btn" href="index.php">Back</a>
                                                        </div>

                </form>
            </div>

                </div>
                <!-- /container -->
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: What is your error message ? Or what is not working ?

Comment: You code does not seem to check for success in the PDO instance - if this comes back false then there was a problem running the query.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the differences between your form and the example you'll see that none of your `<input` fields have the "name" property. This is required in a HTML form input field if you want the server to receive the value - it gets used as the parameter name when the HTTP request is sent, and then in PHP that name is added to the $_POST array with the matching value associated.

So for instance you need to change

```
<input titel="titel" type="text" placeholder="titel" value="<?php echo !empty($titel)?$titel:'';?>">
```

to

```
<input name="titel" titel="titel" type="text" placeholder="titel" value="<?php echo !empty($titel)?$titel:'';?>">
```

and the same for all your other fields, making sure that what you put in the "name" attribute matches what your PHP code is expecting (e.g. `$_POST["titel"]` in this example).

Most HTML forms tutorials will explain this concept if you want to do some further study.